# woocommerce js events do not work as expected

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I use:

```
$(document.body).on('updated_cart_totals', function() {
  $('.woocommerce a#my_remove').css({
    'background-color': randCol
  });
  quantSpinner();
  //console.log('updated_cart_totals');
});

$(document.body).on('wc_cart_emptied', function() {
  $('a.restore-item').css({
    'color': randCol
  });
  //console.log('cart emptied: catches when last item is removed');
});
```

They work as expected.

But the following does not do anything, when an item is removed from the cart:

```
$(document.body).on('removed_from_cart', function() {
  console.log('removed_from_cart');
});
```

Also the next test was negative, nothing happens in the console, when checkout page is loaded:

```
$(document.body).on('update_checkout', function() {
  console.log('init_checkout');
});
```

Any idea how to catch these events properly?

Comment: could be any of hundreds reason, do you get any errors? are you sure your theme triggers `removed_from_cart` etc... link the page would be easier to help

Comment: Yes, i am sure that it triggers 'removed_from_cart'. But for now i found a working solution.

Comment: what was the solution, be sure to add it to your answer could help others

Comment: I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For the checkout page the following works well:

```
$(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function() {
  console.log('updated_checkout');
  $('#payment a').css({
    'color': randCol
  });
});
```

The previous 'removed_from_cart' is irrelevant. Problem solved.